# Asynchronous Calls in SharePoint with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, asynchronous

I am pretty new to SharePoint development. I need your suggestions on using jQuery with Sharepoint. I want to do some asynchronous calls to database like cascading DropDowns etc. Like in normal web site we can create a page and call cs methods from JQuery. My question is how about SharePoint, how we can achieve the same in SharePoint development.

Please suggest

Kind Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will just change the way you deliver the code to your website. Try [creating a webpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817.aspx) first. 
You will need to include a link to [jquery in your masterpage](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/11/20/sharepoint-2007-and-jquery-1.aspx).